# How to navigate using prism for multiple views in Module

Tags: c#, wpf, navigation, prism

I'm new to Prism so need some help on navigation between views
In my project I have just 4 views, so I have created all view in one module. I have created shell and bootstrapper. What I need to do is, I need to pass some data from one view to another(for eg, First view has list of employees, I select one employee and I will click Button to get the details of that employee). Currently I'm using ViewModel first approach`

```
_container.RegisterType<DashboardView>();
_container.RegisterType<PrepareRunView>();

_container.RegisterType<IDashboardViewViewModel, DashboardViewViewModel>();
_container.RegisterType<IPrepareRunViewViewModel, PrepareRunViewViewModel>();
_regionManager.RegisterViewWithRegion(RegionNames.MainRegion, typeof(DashboardView));
_regionManager.RegisterViewWithRegion(RegionNames.MainRegion, typeof(PrepareRunView));
```

1. In this case how do I do navigation between the views and pass data?
2. What do I need to specify in Module class Initialize function?

Moreover in module class when I register both the views for same region, I'm able to see both the views, so I need to activate and deactivate my views also.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

The view-model of the first view (the one where you select an employee) needs a reference to Prism's IRegionManager object. You navigate to the second view and pass it some data as follows, much like querystring values in a URL:-

```
var uriQuery = new UriQuery();
uriQuery.Add("empid", "123");
// Add more name/value pairs if you wish!

var viewName = "your_view_name" + uriQuery;

_regionManager.RequestNavigate("your region name", viewName);
```

As you can see, you navigate to a view by specifying a view name. For this to work, you need to register your views *under a name* with your IoC container (how you do this depends on which container you use).

In the view-model of the view you are navigating to, implement the INavigationAware interface:-

```
    public bool IsNavigationTarget(NavigationContext navigationContext)
    {
        return true;
    }

    public void OnNavigatedFrom(NavigationContext navigationContext)
    {
    }

    public void OnNavigatedTo(NavigationContext navigationContext)
    {
        // This will be called whenever the view is navigated to.
        // Extract the querystring value(s).
        var employeeId = navigationContext.Parameters["empid"];
        .. etc..
    }
```

Comment: Thanks, how do you do activate and deactivate in Module file? It's like when I navigate to different screen, I need to activate the new one.

Answer (score 0):

You can use event aggregator for communication

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff921122.aspx

Comment: How do I activate and deactivate views in Module?